# Reverse of number in PHP not showing correct output

Tags: php

I have made a program to reverse the number but every time `0` gets appended to the result.

```
$num = 675;
$rev = 0;

while($num > 0) {
$temp = $num % 10;
$rev = ($rev *  10) + $temp;
$num = (int) $num / 10;
}

echo $rev;   //result is 5760
```

Comment: Replace $num = (int) $num / 10; with this code $num = (int) ($num / 10); which is correct solution given by @Karoly Horvath

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is this line:

```
$num = (int) $num / 10;
```

which is the same as:

```
$num = ((int) $num) / 10;
```

so it doesn't actually cast the result. Use the extra parentheses:

```
$num = (int) ($num / 10);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is you complete code.

```
<?php
$n = 3456;
$reverse = 0;
while ($n > 0)
{
  $reverse = $reverse * 10;
  $reverse = $reverse + $n%10;
  $n = (int)($n/10);
}
echo $reverse;
?>
```

Output will be 6543

Answer (score 3):

In php you can do `$rev = (int)strrev($num);`

Comment: Actually. Also, this is a faster way, at least for huge numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by your goal bt this...

```
$num = 675;
$num_array = str_split($num);
$final_num_array = array_reverse($num_array);
$rev_num = implode("",$final_num_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
<?php
    $num = 675;
    $strNum = (string) $num;
    $revStrNum = strrev($strNum);
    $revNum = (int) $revStrNum;
    echo $revNum; //Output 576 when I tried it
?>
```

Notice, I utilised the string function [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `strrev`:

```
$>cat r.php
<?php
$num=675;

$rev= (int) strrev("{$num}");

echo "{$num} : {$rev}".PHP_EOL;
?>

$>php r.rev
675 : 576
```

Answer (score 1):

This 100% works:-

```
 $mac = 123;
 $step1 = strrev((string)$mac);
 $step2 = (int)$step1;

 echo $mac." and ".$step2*2;//checking
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a number reverser I found online:

```
<?php 
$num=6541020; 
$revnum=0; 
do{ 
    $revnum=($revnum *10)+($num % 10); 
    $num=(int)($num / 10 ); 
}while($num>0); 
echo $revnum; 
?>
```

Source: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4879

Answer (score 0):

$num = 675;
    $rev = 0;

```
while($num > 1) { //do $num value lent-1
$temp = intval($num) % 10;
$rev = intval($rev) *  10 + $temp;
$num =  intval($num)/ 10;
}

echo $rev;
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple, try this:

```
$num = 4321;
$rev = 0;

while($num > 1) {
    $temp = $num % 10;  
    $num = (int) $num / 10;
    echo $temp;
}
```

output:

```
1234
```